# In Datatables, start value resets to 0, when column sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, pagination, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm using Datatables.js version 1.9, and doing server-side implementation. Pagination is working fine but, the start param is resets to 0 value if do sorting on any column.

For example If a go to 3rd or 4th page, the value of start should be persistent but here Datatables sending every time 0 value on subsequent http requests. I Checked length (no.of records per page) param, it's good when doing sorting but start param is resets to 0. Any please suggest me on this.

[image]

Comment: "If I go to 3rd or 4th page, the value of start should be persistent" - should it?  Why?  You've changed the sort, you'd want to start again at the top where the sort has had an effect.  Seems like a UX question rather than a technical one.

Comment: if you change the sort you should be back on page 1 [see answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/129076)